# Почему не выбирается radio по группам?

Tags: html, css, form, input

```
<form action="test_2.php" method="post">

<span style="margin-left: 250px">binary</span><span style="margin-left: 30px">decimal</span>
<span style="margin-left: 30px">hexadecimal</span> <br>

Number 1: <input type="text" name="number_1">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="binary" style="margin-left: 15px">
<label><input type="radio" name="type" value="decimal" style="margin-left: 56px" checked>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" value="hexadecimal" style="margin-left: 80px">

<br>

Number 2: <input type="text" name="number_2">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="binary" style="margin-left: 15px">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="decimal" style="margin-left: 56px" checked>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="hexadecimal" style="margin-left: 80px">

<br>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Есть вот такая форма, где вводятся 2 числа и выбираются их типы. Так вот вопрос: что написать, чтобы тип первого и второго чисел выбирались отдельно?
Пробовал через  привязывать каждое radio к полю, но без толку.
Работает если создать 2 формы, но это не вариант.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дайте группам радио-кнопок разные атрибуты `name`:

```html
<form action="test_2.php" method="post">

<span style="margin-left: 250px">binary</span>
<span style="margin-left: 30px">decimal</span>
<span style="margin-left: 30px">hexadecimal</span> 

<br>

Number 1: <input type="text" name="number_1">
<input type="radio" name="type_1" value="binary" style="margin-left: 15px">
<input type="radio" name="type_1" value="decimal" style="margin-left: 56px" checked>
<input type="radio" name="type_1" value="hexadecimal" style="margin-left: 80px">

<br>

Number 2: <input type="text" name="number_2">
<input type="radio" name="type_2" value="binary" style="margin-left: 15px">
<input type="radio" name="type_2" value="decimal" style="margin-left: 56px" checked>
<input type="radio" name="type_2" value="hexadecimal" style="margin-left: 80px">

<br>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вот я дурень ...